# Error de script al cargar sitio web en Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, firefox

Al cargar un sitio ya en el servidor remoto, éste nunca termina de cargar, en la barra de carga se mantiene el icono de "cargando", y en la consola, me aparece este error:

```
    El uso de getPreventDefault() está desaprobada. Usa defaultPrevented en su lugar.
jquery.min.js:5:12223

unreachable code after return statement
[Saber más]
js:64:1196

Hubo un fallo al cargar el <script> con fuente “blob:https://www.vitalarmy.com/d0421915-ce39-4c46-84a7-11c6d6355dec”.
desarrollo:1
```

Abro el sitio en otros navegadores y al parecer no se presenta este mismo problema. En todos borré cache, cookies, sesión, todo, pero en `Firefox` permanece funcionando mal.

Comment: Deberías poner el código para ver exactemente el error

Comment: No esque no hay código como tal mio, lo que marca es directamente de jquery, no marca ninguna línea del código que yo estoy realizando, se me hace extraño en realidad.

Comment: El error de `jquery`, es por la versión de Firefox, pero solo avisa, no para la ejecución de la web, tu error viene en la línea `Hubo un fallo al cargar el <script> con fuente “blob:https://www.vitalarmy.com/d0421915-ce39-4c46-84a7-11c6d6355dec”.
desarrollo:1`

Comment: Pero "desarrollo" es una ruta solamente, es mi directorio de pruebas del sitio actualmente, el sitio está disponible temporalmente en esa misma url: https://www.vitalarmy.com/desarrollo/

Comment: Al parecer el problema es al cargar el websocket de zendesk, ¿puedes deshabilitarlo un momento y recargar la página?

Comment: En efecto @kacos , ya lo retire, y el sitio carga correctamente, creo que tiene que ver que el script se actualizó al haber terminado la versión de prueba de la plataforma de zendesk. Muchas gracias, disculpa, puedes decirme como lograste deducir eso, para utilizar eso en futuras ocasiones; es interesante, porque de hecho pasa lo mismo en la web de zendesk, no deja de cargar.

Comment: Que bueno que pude ayudarte un poco! Pues nada mas fue descartar problemas, supuse que podía ser algo con una carga externa de scripts así que mi primer sospechoso fue zendesk, bloquee las entradas de websocket y ahí salieron varios errores similares al que te aparecía a ti, te pedí que lo deshabilites un momento para poder descartar que zendesk era el causante y resultó que si era el problema, espero encontrar una solución para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias @kacos probablemente se deba a alguna petición que Firefox no sabe cómo atrapar o solucionar, porque Opera y Chrome no daban ningún problema, solo persistía en Firefox; probé entrando en modo "seguro sin complementos" y ahí resulto bien, siento que algo debe estar siendo bloqueado por el navegador, no sé la razón de esto. Pero bueno, momentaniamente, funciona sin problemas ya.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso fue por el protocolo que usas para los servicios *(scripts, para la URL en general)*, en mi caso tenía `https` pero en realidad era `http` el correcto.

Una vez cambiando ese protocolo a `http` ya me funcionó.

Comment: tambien deberías añadir que esto ocurre cuando se insertan archivos js con una url statica... en lugar de la opción self hosted...